# The code is showing syntax error "tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4)"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

We were trying to get started in tensorflow so and we got this error in the celsius to fahrenheit example code of tf.

its a syntax error but as compared to tutorial it looks the same

```
`celsius    = np.array([8,10,12,14,16], dtype = float) #data
 fahrenheit = np.array([12,13,14,15,16], dtype = float) #data
 model = tf.keras.Sequential([ #setting model 
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4, input_shape=[1]) 
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4) #error in the network 
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
 ])`
```

well we are trying to create our first neural network but got stuck here

Answer (score 1):

Your are adding a list to the model, so the list entries have to be seperated by a `,` instead of only a new line (after each of the dense layers).

Try this:

```
celsius    = np.array([8,10,12,14,16], dtype = float) #data
 fahrenheit = np.array([12,13,14,15,16], dtype = float) #data
 model = tf.keras.Sequential([ #setting model 
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4, input_shape=[1]), #just added , here (and in the next line)
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4), #error in the network 
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
 ])
```